# Gaps in html UL Lists on IE & Firefox Only. Chrome Displays ok

Tags: css, list

Hello i seem to be having a problem with an html list across a few browsers. My page and code can be viewed here-
http://onlinebanter.com/latest

Its the last 4 comments block in the main area. As you can see from attached screenshot things are not good in IE and Firefox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp5GL.jpg

On chrome everything works great. I cant work out how to get rid of that pesky big blank space. Tried everything. All suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `padding` of your `.views-field-picture` class in your css, remove this:

`padding: 4px;`

And it should look like this:

```
.views-field-picture {
    width: 23px;
}
```

Hope it helps!